# jQuery on ready and change

Tags: jquery, function, document-ready

the problem is that the `jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').hide()` don't run except if i choose another value from "form_auction_type" and went back to the older value.

i need the script to run on page load and also on changing values of the drop down box "form_auction_type"

```
jQuery('#form_auction_type').change(function(e) {
    if(jQuery('#form_auction_type').val() == '2'){
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').show(); 
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_current').hide(); 
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_reserve').hide(); 
    } else { 
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').hide(); 
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_reserve').show();  
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_current').show(); 
    } 
});
```

to make it a lil bit easier changing this line from

```
jQuery('#form_auction_type').change(function(e) {
```

to

```
jQuery('#form_auction_type').ready(function(e) {
```

fixes my problem, but the drop down menu isn't working anymore!

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML. There isn't enough info to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply trigger change on page load with `.trigger('change')`. This will cause the anon function to run.

```
jQuery('#form_auction_type').change(function(e) {
    if (jQuery('#form_auction_type').val() == '2') {
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').show();
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_current').hide();
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_reserve').hide();
    } else {
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').hide();
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_reserve').show();
        jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_current').show();
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: i want to hide "form-row-rapper-price_bin" if "form_auction_type" = 1, which is the default on page load. sorry your method didn't work

Comment: Then you haven't given enough information. Please provide your HTML.

Comment: why do you need more of the HTML ?? my problem is with the script above and like i've said toggling the drop down menu fixes the issue, how can i run the script on page load??

Comment: That runs on page load. The HTML is required because it seems that the desired selected value is not the default value of the select option. Without the HTML it's impossible to make the code do what you want, because it does as was requested and there's an unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a function and call it from both places. You can even tuck it inside the `ready` callback so it's not a global (if you're not already using a scoping function):

```
jQuery(function() {
    function updateDisplay() {
        if(jQuery('#form_auction_type').val() == '2'){
            jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').show(); 
            jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_current').hide(); 
            jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_reserve').hide(); 
        } else { 
            jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_bin').hide(); 
            jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_reserve').show();  
            jQuery('#form-row-rapper-price_current').show(); 
        } 
    }

    updateDisplay();
    jQuery('#form_auction_type').change(updateDisplay);
});
```